# Seeting the Calendar Object in Java

Tags: java

I have the respective name of the month e.g JANUARY or FEBRUARY in a String variable.

Now how do I set the month of a Calendar object in java using this String variable.

I tried setting via calendar.set method but it takes only int values.

Comment: @Paul Bellora: Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection to extract the value of the field (see the `monthValue()` function).

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthValue("January"));
        System.out.println(c.getTime());
    }

    public static int monthValue(String monthName)
            throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
        Field monthConstant = Calendar.class.getField(monthName.toUpperCase());
        return monthConstant.getInt(null);
    }
}
```